# MarkLogic - developing a third party backup and recovery solution

Tags: marklogic

We are developing a solution for Backup and recovery of  Marklogic databases.
Below are the requirements

- We need to take Full and Incremental backup in our own supported formats
- Recovery of databases at granular level
- We would like to avoid backup staging location to improve performance and save storage

We think of following strategies

- File System Snapshot-

  We can put the forest into flash backup mode and take the FS snapshot and move data to our backup solution. 
  Do you see any consistency issue in this approach? Also the incremental backup is challenge here. Any comments?
- MLCP

  We are considering option of exporting database through MLCP. We see that mlcp supports snapshots, so we can export consistent point in time backup here.
- Backup Using REST API of MarkLogic

  Marklogic has its own API for backup which writes at staging location. Is there any way to avoid staging location?

Which of the above solution will best fit for our requirements? Please suggest any other available approach.

Answer (score 1):

Could you expand on "in our own supported formats". 
All but 'b' is incompatible with "our own formats' (unless your format is simply a container format)

I would not recommend file system backups for normal 'database backup' operations.  There is the issues of uncommitted transactions etc but those are recoverable -- the bigger issue is the selectivity of what your are backing up and what you intend to do with it. 
If you want to restore a failed system then a FS backup is fine -- that is what is used for AWS standard configurations (EBS Volumes) -- although it is *always best* to shut down the server first.   File System backups wont get you incremental very easily, in fact its counter-productive due to how merges work.

There are also several data sets to consider -- the normal 'database data', the configuration files, any OS, environment variables, startup params etc.
VERY IMPORTANT is that the hostname is used in multiple locations -- do NOT copy fileystem backups to a different host and run them unchanged -- worse case is if its on the same subnet its possible to launch such a 'cloned' server into the original cluster when you intended it to be standalone.

Which brings one to clusters -- Depending on your use case you may or may not want to backup the cluster as a whole.

Recommended solutions are analogous to the same question wrt other application backups -- Look at the intent of the backup, which is typically some kind of restore ...
A) Restore entire failed cluster  --- a FS snapshot is a good start, but should be accompanied with database level backups.
B) Restore a failed node -- Just that node's configurations, plus all attached storage
C) Restore a 'Database'  -- Use the built in API's for running backups and incrementals.
D) Restore a failed volume -- Use replication 
E) Restore individual files  -- Use mlcp or similar to get documents backed up.

Note:  A "Database" is comprised of a lot more then just the documents -- (collections, permissions, users , locks, property files etc).
For full fidelity I recommend using the built in backup/restore for *all use cases* except 
A) Where you really just want a 'plain file' restored -- 
B) Distributed backups -- consider using a foreign cluster to offload the data to a non-production cluster and backup from there.

I also recommend, as typical for other apps as well, a combination of filesystem snapshots and database level backups.   They solve different problems  --

As for 'without staging' -- what do you mean ? Staging is where the data goes -- its got to go *somewhere*.   You can backup to AWS S3 or network storage -- you get to define where the target is, but its got to be *something*